# rails 3 caching: expire action for named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

My controller has this:

```
caches_action :render_ticker_for_channel, :expires_in => 30.seconds
```

In my routes file I have this:

```
match '/render_c_t/:channel_id' => 'render#render_ticker_for_channel', :as => :render_channel_ticker
```

In the log file I see this:

```
Write fragment views/mcr3.dev/render_c_t/63 (11.6ms)
```

How do I expire this manually? I need to expire this from a different controller than the render controller, but even within the render controller I can't get it to expire the right thing.

If I do:

```
 expire_action(:controller => 'render', :action => 'render_ticker_for_channel', :id => c.id)
```

I see:

```
Expire fragment views/mcr3.dev/render/render_ticker_for_channel/63 (3.2ms)
```

If I do:

```
expire_action(:controller => 'render', :action => 'render_c_t', :id => c.id)
```

I see:

```
Expire fragment views/mcr3.dev/render/render_c_t/63 (3.2ms)
```

This:

```
expire_action("render_c_t/#{c.id}")
```

produces:

```
Expire fragment views/render_c_t/63 (3.5ms)
```

How can I get it to expire the same path that 'caches_action' is producing?!

Comment: I'm not confident enough to add this as a full fledged answer, but have you tried the back door? `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` will give you access to your helpers and returns a string that's the path and/or url that would be sent to the browser in a Location header. Try `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.render_ticker_for_channel_path(63)` and `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.render_ticker_for_channel(63, :host => 'mcr3.dev')` You might be able to pass the resulting string (with some manipulation) to `expire_action` and get it find the right cached chunk. Ugly, but might work

Answer (score 5):

Use the regex version of [expire_fragment](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html#method-i-expire_fragment):

```
expire_fragment %r{render_c_t/#{c.id}/}
```

Comment: if you have cache on **file_store**, this is the best way to expire with RegEx

Answer (score 0):

There should definitely be a more "Rails Way" to do this, but this might work as a back door: `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` will give you access to your helpers and each will return a string that's the path and/or url that would be sent to the browser in a Location header.

Try `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.render_ticker_for_channel_path(63)` which should return `/render_c_t/63` and `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.render_ticker_for_channel(63, :host => 'mcr3.dev')` which should return `http://mcr3.dev/render_c_t/63`

With some manipulation you could parse apart that second string to get back to the name that Rails is using for the cached action:

```
def funky_action_cache_name(route, params)
  Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send(route.to_s+'_url', params).gsub(/https?:\/\//,'')
end

# expire_action(funky_action_cache_name(:render_ticker_for_channel, :id => 63))
```

Not the most beautiful solution, but should work!

Answer (score -1):

```
caches_action :render_ticker_for_channel, :if => proc do 
  !!params['doCache']
end
```

But for this solution to work we need to pass an extra param either through query string or post body.