# rails3 caching: expire fragment with extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, fragment-caching

**How do I expire a fragment in the cache with a file extension (.json) from a another controller?**

I am using Rails 3.2.8.

I have two controllers for the same models: /admin/books_controller and /api/books_controller.  The admin controller is used to create/update/delete books and requires elevated access.  The api/books_controller is used to search/list view details about a book by users.  I've attempted to cache the api/books_controller

```
class Api::BooksController < ApiController
  caches_action :show

  def show    
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

This works great.  The first request is slow and the second is fast

```
Rendered api/books/show.json.rabl (119.7ms)
Write fragment views/localhost:3000/api/books/4.json (1.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 568ms (Views: 124.2ms | ActiveRecord: 9.5ms)

Read fragment views/localhost:3000/api/books/4.json (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
```

Now, I need to expire the the fragments when the Book is updated or destroyed.  I have this:

```
class Admin::BooksController < AdminController

  def update
    @book.attributes = params[:book]
    if (@book.save)
      expire_action(:controller => 'api/books', :action => 'show', :id => @book.id, :format => 'json')
    end
  end

end
```

However, **this doesn't resolve to the same fragment** (the request is an HTML request now, to a different controller):

```
Started PUT "/admin/books/4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-08 12:27:11 -0600
Processing by Admin::BooksController#update as HTML
...
Expire fragment views/localhost:3000/api/books/4 (0.1ms)
```

My API controller with a JSON request reads and writes this fragment:

```
views/localhost:3000/api/books/4.json
```

My Admin controller tries to expire this fragment:

```
views/localhost:3000/api/books/4
```

**How do I expire views/localhost:3000/api/books/4.json from the other controller with a different request format?**

This question: [rails 3 caching: expire action for named route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076721/rails-3-caching-expire-action-for-named-route) indicates I could use a regex to expire multiple fragments, but that requires the keys in the cache to be enumerable (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html#method-i-expire_fragment)

Comment: Executing the `expire_action` with `:format => 'json'` produces `Expire fragment views/localhost:3000/api/books/4`? Is it the problem? I'm having a hard time clearly understanding what's the issue.

Comment: Yes, I expected it to produce views/localhost:3000/api/books/4.json

Comment: I tried it in my app ... and it works as expected `Expire fragment views/www.example.com/api/books/show/1.json` ... can you try to do an `expire_action` with a `format` param on some very basic action, like your homepage?

Comment: Also try using `expire_fragment` instead with the same params to see if that makes a difference

Comment: It looks like the problem was in my routes:

  namespace :api, :defaults => {:format => 'json'} do
    resources :books, :only => [:show]
  end

This caused params[:format] to be set in my api controller, but not in my admin controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem was with routing setting default parameters.  In the API controller, params[:format] was 'json' and in the Admin controller it was nil.

When I added this to my Admin controller:

```
params[:format] = 'json'
expire_action(:controller => 'api/books', :action => 'show', :id => @book.id, :format => 'json')
```

Then, the fragments in both controllers matched.

This let me back to my routes:

In my routes I had this:

```
namespace :api, :defaults => {:format => 'json'} do
  resources :books, :only => [:show]
end
```

This caused params[:format] to be set in my api namespace.  I didn't have anything in my admin namespace and apparently actionpack/ActionCachePath saw these two differently.  Removing the defaults in the routes fixed the problem.