# expiring action from a different controller

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two controllers like this

```
class New::StoresController < ApplicationController
  caches_action :index, cache_path: Proc.new {|c| c.params}, expires_in: cache_time(:long)
  caches_action :show, cache_path: Proc.new {|c| c.params}, expires_in: cache_time(:long)
  def index
  end
  def show
     # Here I use param[:store], params[:locale] and params[:ref]
  end
end

class New::StoreReviewsController < ApplicationController
  def create
     expire_action controller: '/new/stores', action: :show, \
                   store:params[:store], locale:"en", ref:"stores"
  end
end
```

I want to expire action New::StoresController#show on creation of a new StoreReview.

When the show action of Store is executed, the cache reads the following

> Cache read: views/localhost:3000/en/stores/store-name
>
> Read fragment views/localhost:3000/en/stores/store-name

While expire_action expires this fragment

> Expire fragment views/localhost:3000/en/search?action=show&controller=new/stores&ref=stores 
>   Cache delete: views/localhost:3000/en/search?action=show&controller=new/stores

The question is should I use `expire_fragment` instead of `expire_action` as mentioned here ? [rails 3 caching: expire action for named route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076721/rails-3-caching-expire-action-for-named-route)

Also if I want to cache the action but not with all params what is the best way to do it?

Currently that's what I am doing

```
caches_action :show, cache_path: Proc.new {|c| c.params.select{ |p| [:controller,:action ,"locale", "store"].include? p} }, expires_in: cache_time(:long)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the answer for that.

By default `caches_action` ignores parameters.

And for getting the right fragment to be expired I did the following

```
expire_action store_url(host: my_host, store: store_name, locale: locale])
```